# Creating a triangle shape in a UIButton

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I am trying to create a button with a triangle icon/shape in it. I have created the triangle in `Paintcode` then copied the beizer path and added it to the button layer as below.

```
-(void)setupShowHideRouteButton {
    UIBezierPath* bezierPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
    [bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(10.5, 8.5)];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(40.5, 8.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(39.5, 8.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(40.5, 8.5)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(26.39, 22.3)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(25.2, 23.5)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(10.5, 8.5)];
    [UIColor.blackColor setStroke];
    bezierPath.lineWidth = 1;
    [bezierPath stroke];

    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.frame = self.showHideRouteViewBtn.bounds;
    shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2;
    [self.showHideRouteViewBtn.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
}
```

However, this does not appear to work. I am setting the background color of the UIButton so I know the frame is correct and outlet working as expected it is just not adding the shape?

**Second Approach**

```
UIBezierPath* bezierPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
[bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(10.5, 8.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(40.5, 8.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(39.5, 8.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(40.5, 8.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(26.39, 22.3)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(25.2, 23.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(10.5, 8.5)];
[UIColor.blackColor setStroke];
bezierPath.lineWidth = 1;
[bezierPath stroke];

// Create a mask layer and the frame to determine what will be visible in the view.
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
CGRect maskRect = self.showHideRouteViewBtn.bounds;

// Create a path with the rectangle in it.
CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithRect(maskRect, NULL);

// Set the path to the mask layer.
maskLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;

// Release the path since it's not covered by ARC.
CGPathRelease(path);

// Set the mask of the view.
self.showHideRouteViewBtn.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

This did not work either.

Comment: Try masking the layer

Comment: If you set the `backgroundColor` of the shape layer, can you confirm that it’s correctly aligned inside the view?

Comment: @troop231 - See the second approach in question, this did not work for me either

Comment: Please provide your `UIButton` setup code so I can see the frame size, color, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.frame = self.showHideRouteViewBtn.bounds;
shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2;
self.showHideRouteViewBtn.layer.mask = shapeLayer;
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I also noticed a stupid mistake I made along the way which resolved it... Too late at night, my bad! Thanks

Comment: Gotta wait 5 mins, you'll get it :)